# Getting json value from nested response

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have the following json return. I wish to get all the value in car, car.Make and car.Price. How can it be done? I have tried this but not working

```js
$.each(jqXHR.responseJSON.ModelState(index, value), function() {
  alert(jqXHR.responseJSON.ModelState[index].value);
});
```

[image]

```js
{
    "Message": "The request is invalid.",
    "ModelState": { 
        "car": [
            "Required property 'Make' not found in JSON. Path '', line 1, position 57."
        ],
        "car.Make" : [
            "The Make field is required."
        ], 
        "car.Price": [
            "The field Price must be between 0 and 200000."
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: ``ModelState`` is a single object, iniside it is ``car`` array and in ``car.Make`` and ``car.Price`` array, do loop on  ``ModelState.car``

Comment: This presumably shows the failed (?) output. To help you fix this, the *input* data structure is needed.

Comment: Access car: `myObject.ModelState.car[0]` Is this type of answer you are looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would get the 3 values like this:

```
alert(json.ModelState["car"]);
alert(json.ModelState["car.Make"]);
alert(json.ModelState["car.Price"]);
```

this will also work for car

```
alert(json.ModelState.car);
```

Since the other properties contain a '.' in the name then it looks for a property Make on property car rather than property called car.Make therefore we need to use the string key.

Notice in this fiddle the last two are undefined. Best not to use '.' property names if going to be used in json.

https://jsfiddle.net/1zgybf9m/

To print all data in modelState and all cars, assuming you can have more than one. IT would be more like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/1zgybf9m/1/

```
var json = {
    "Message": "The request is invalid.",
    "ModelState": { 
        "car": [
            "1 Required property 'Make' not found in JSON. Path '', line 1, position 57.",
            "2 Required property 'Make' not found in JSON. Path '', line 1, position 57."
        ],
        "car.Make" : [
            "1 The Make field is required.",
            "2 The Make field is required."
        ], 
        "car.Price": [
            "1 The field Price must be between 0 and 200000.",
            "2 The field Price must be between 0 and 200000."
        ]
    }
}

for(var prop in json.ModelState){
    console.log(prop);
    for(var value in json.ModelState[prop]){
       console.log(json.ModelState[prop][value]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Having a variable with the JSON:

```
var obj= {

        "Message": "The request is invalid.",
        "ModelState": { 
            "car": [
                "Required property 'Make' not found in JSON. Path '', line 1, position 57."
            ],
            "car.Make" : [
                "The Make field is required."
            ], 
            "car.Price": [
                "The field Price must be between 0 and 200000."
            ]
        }
    };
```

For loop access through ModelState:

```
for (var prop in obj.ModelState){
    for (var i=0; i<obj.ModelState[prop].length; i++){
        console.log(obj.ModelState[prop][i]);    
    }    
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m8gq0Lew/2/

It is also recommended not to use `.` in JSON-keys

Comment: i need to loop through it instead of getting it explicitly one by one

Comment: as stated above ModelState will only be one object so this will print each property but car, car.Make and car.Price are arrays